# Linux - flip last bottom lines only, with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, lines, flip

We are currently learning some awk commands to manipulate/rearrange  text on files.

our original text goes like this..1998

```
    Ford,mondeo,1998,5800
    ford,fiesta,1994,4575
    Chevy,impala,1998,1000
    Plymouth,Fury,1992,2000
    Dodge,charger,1989,5950
    Ford,F150,1991,1450
```

It's asking us to rearrange the columns (part one) which i already did..
but at the same time to flip the bottom two lines (part two) so that it looks like this

```
1998 5800 Ford mondeo
1994 4575 ford fiesta
1998 1000 Chevy impala
1992 2000 Plymouth Fury
1991 1450 Ford  F150
1989 5950 Dodge charger
```

again, i got the order and spacing taken care of, but how do i switch the bottom two lines (or flip them). by the way this can only be done with awk.

Comment: can you please edit your post your to include code that shows what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code switches the last two lines of a file:

```
awk '{array[NR%3]=$0; 
    if(NR>2){print array[(NR+1)%3]}}
    END{print array[NR%3]; 
        print array[(NR-1)%3]}' test
```

To do so, we store the last three lines in an array. We print a line only when line after the next line is read. Finally, we take last two lines from the array, invert the order and print it.

**A more detailed description of the code**:
We store the content of the current line (`$0`) in an array. As we only need to keep track of the last three lines read, the index of our array can be limited to the values 0, 1, and 2. We achieve this by using the modulo operator (`NR % 3`).
When reaching the third line, we print the last but one line (`if(NR>2)...`). This is save, as in this case there are still two lines in the array that we can handle separately.
When the end of the file is reached (`END{...}`), we print the last two lines in inverse order.
Why did we use `NR%3` (and not `NR%2`)? If there were only two lines in our input file, printing must happen in the `END`-block and not before!

Comment: That's the right way to do it, and just add `awk -F, '{$0=$3" "$4" "$1" "$2} ` to the front and you'll solve the "column" reformatting part of your question too.

Comment: This worked like charm!, however, im relative new to awk, could you explain each line please?, for example the modulus 3, why are you dividing by 3?, and whats the point of setting a=NR?

Comment: @user1986245: I have added a more detailed explanation to my answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @user1986245: variable `a` was not necessary. I removed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this will swap the last two lines and prints omitted for the others

```
$ tac cars | awk 'NR==1{getline one} 
                  NR==2{print; print one} 
                   NR>2{print "omitted"}' | tac  
omitted
omitted
omitted
Plymouth,Fury,1992,2000
Dodge,charger,1989,5950
```

you can add formatting.  Similarly can be without `tac` with logic in `END` block.

UPDATE: awk only solution: keep two lines in memory, when done print them in reverse order

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print pp} 
           {pp=p;p=$0} 
        END{print p;print pp}' car 

Ford,mondeo,1998,5800                                                                                          
ford,fiesta,1994,4575                                                                                          
Chevy,impala,1998,1000                                                                                         
Plymouth,Fury,1992,2000                                                                                        
Ford,F150,1991,1450                                                                                            
Dodge,charger,1989,5950
```

Comment: omitted is not actually part of the final result.. i just typed in omitted to not have to write the first 4 lines.. but the final result should actually should like this (see edit on post).. by the way, we cant use anything other than AWK.